# How do I query my collection efficiently based on timeStamps saved with new Date()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60acdcc693407d2c7b97dd68"),
    "transDate" : "2021-06-03T13:53:12.238Z",
    "transAmount" : "200",
    "transPayersName" : "Daniela",
    "transPayersAge" : "24",
    "transPayersGender" : "Female",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I'd like to draw your attention specifically to the **transDate**.
The following code is what I used when inserting the data into the collection:

```
var transAction = new Date().toISOString(); 
transAction.transDate = transDate;
transAction.transAmount = transAmount;
transAction.transPayersName = transPayersName;
transAction.transPayersAge = transPayersAge;
transAction.transPayersGender = transPayersGender;
transAction.save( (err)=>{
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error inserting into Database: ' +err)
    }
```

Now, I am looking for a more efficient way to query the collection based on the **transDate**.
I currently query the collection this way:

```
db.getCollection('mydbs').find({"transDate" : { "$gte": "2021-05-03T13:53:12.238Z" }});
```

The code above correctly yields:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60acdcc693407d2c7b97dd68"),
    "transDate" : "Tue May 25 2021 14:17:26 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)",
    "transAmount" : "200",
    "transPayersName" : "Daniela",
    "transPayersAge" : "24",
    "transPayersGender" : "Female",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I believe there is a more efficient way to query the database based on the time stored in the **transDate**.

Your suggestions are welcome

Comment: always try to store ISO format and in date type i.e `"2021-06-03T13:25:42.269Z"`.

Comment: @turivishal Thank you! You will notice that I have updated the code to insert using ISO format as you suggested! Isn't there a better way to query, stay for instance using moment.js? Would this work?

Comment: i think this is good, and it would be very good if you store it as date type. see this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GO38SNKC79M)